# Compare triple variable pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 3 variable in pl/sql

```
a_ varchar2(10);
b_ varchar2(10);
c_ varchar2(10);
```

How to compare that 3 variable are equal.
If variable a_ is null then is equal with b_ and c_. b_ and c_ also can be null.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you mean; you seem to be redefining 'equal' but you'll need to expand on exactly how. Maybe add some sample values and the expected result for each combination **to the question** (not as comments), as well as trying to describe the logic more fully?

Comment: for example a_ = null b_ = 'abc' c_ = 'abc' are equal, If all variable are null there also equal

Comment: Nope, not really any clearer. Do you mean you want to test if all non-null values are the same?

Comment: yes if variable is a_ is null and that mean is equla with b_ and c_

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to compare all of the non-null values, you could coalesce the three values and vary the order they are evaluated, and compare the result; I think this covers all bases:

```
if coalesce(a_, b_, c_) = coalesce(b_, c_, a_)
  and coalesce(b_, c_, a_) = coalesce(c_, a_, b_) then
  -- they are 'equal'
else
  -- they are not 'equal'
end if;
```

Quick demo using a local procedure:

```
declare
  procedure checkit (a_ varchar2, b_ varchar2, c_ varchar2) is
  begin
    dbms_output.put('a_ <' || a_ || '> b_ <' || b_ || '> c_ <' || c_ || '> are ');

    if coalesce(a_, b_, c_) = coalesce(b_, c_, a_)
      and coalesce(b_, c_, a_) = coalesce(c_, a_, b_) then
      dbms_output.put_line('equal');
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('not equal');
    end if;
  end checkit;

begin
  checkit ('abc', null, null);
  checkit (null, 'abc', null);
  checkit (null, null, 'abc');
  checkit (null, 'abc', 'abc');
  checkit ('abc', null, 'abc');
  checkit ('abc', 'abc', null);

  checkit ('abc', null, 'def');
  checkit ('abc', 'def', null);
  checkit (null, 'abc', 'def');    
end;
/

a_ <abc> b_ <> c_ <> are equal
a_ <> b_ <abc> c_ <> are equal
a_ <> b_ <> c_ <abc> are equal
a_ <> b_ <abc> c_ <abc> are equal
a_ <abc> b_ <> c_ <abc> are equal
a_ <abc> b_ <abc> c_ <> are equal
a_ <abc> b_ <> c_ <def> are not equal
a_ <abc> b_ <def> c_ <> are not equal
a_ <> b_ <abc> c_ <def> are not equal
```

If you want all three values being null to count as 'equal' then you'd need to handle that too; so it would be:

```
if coalesce(a_, b_, c_) is null
  or (coalesce(a_, b_, c_) = coalesce(b_, c_, a_)
    and coalesce(b_, c_, a_) = coalesce(c_, a_, b_)) then
  -- they are 'equal'
else
  -- they are not 'equal'
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

unclear exact what you want, but this will check if all the items are equal regardless of nulls

```
if nvl(a,'rabbit')= nvl(b,'rabbit')
and nvl(a,'rabbit') = nvl(c,'rabbit')
then
  -- all are equal
else 
  -- all are not equal
end if
```

Comment: That's checking that all three are either null or equal to a certain value ('rabbit'); not just whether they are all equal to each other. But it isn't really clear which is required...

Comment: Not quite Alex. If they are all equal, and not null and not "rabbit" this will still show them as equal.

Comment: True, but it won't work if any of them is null and the others are not 'rabbit', even if they are the same; with the OP's example of null/abc/abc, for example.

Comment: i see what you mean, i think i misunderstood what the original question was asking